# Minify client through Play Framework

Tags: javascript, html, playframework, minify, typesafe-activator

How can I minify JS & CSS through play-framework?

'Google Closure Compiler' is no longer an option since it was removed.

I am using play Activator 2.3.7

Note: This question is not duplicate since Google Closure Compiler was removed from activator 2.3.7.

Comment: The answer there is no longer an option since google closure compiler was removed from play framework 2.3.7

Comment: Apologies. You might want to use sbt plugins such as: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web https://github.com/rgcottrell/sbt-html-minifier https://github.com/eltimn/sbt-closure

Answer (score 5):

Play 2.4 is the same.

- Add empty main.js to public folder
- plugins.sbt:

  ```
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
  ```
- build.sbt:

  ```
    pipelineStages := Seq(rjs)
  ```
- Generate production executable:

  ```
    $activator stage
  ```
- Run results:

  ```
    ./target/universal/stage/bin/<yourproject>
  ```

Note: when running activator stage you should see it output the process of minifying/uglifying:

> ...
>
> [info] Tracing dependencies for: main
>
> [info] Uglify2 file: /path/to/your/project/public/something.js
>
> ...

Comment: I've used gulp instead

Answer (score 4):

You can use RequireJS. It is documented [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/RequireJS-support), but basically is just to add the following in the `build.sbt`

```
pipelineStages := Seq(rjs)
```

Then add this line to the file `project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
```

As RequireJS website states

> Combines related scripts together into build layers and minifies them via UglifyJS (the default) or Closure Compiler (an option when using Java).
>
> Optimizes CSS by inlining CSS files referenced by @import and removing comments.

Comment: After I've added this to build.sbt, I didn't understand how can I activate the minification and concatenation from the documentation.https://github.com/sbt/sbt-rjs#sbt-rjs
Do you have an example?

Comment: Is added automatically IN PRODUCTION only. `activator start` or `activator stage`

Comment: I've written activator start, and when looking in the files in chrome F12 they are neither minified or concatenated.

Comment: Check my last edit. It works for me and it's documented in that same way, so it should work for you.

Comment: Maybe can you upload an example?