# Play 2.4.3 Problems with assets while starting application

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Please help me fix the problem with assets that appeared during the update play version from 2.3 to 2.4

Earlier, when the application was started by command - sbt “run 9005”, application.min.js and application.min.css were automatically created.

[image: link]

And assets looks like:

[image: link]

After update Play and Sbt versions, i got this errors:

[image: link]
And assets disappeared:

[image: link]

My routes:

[image: link]

And template:

[image: link]

If you need build.sbt

[image: link]

EDIT 1:
Perhaps the problem is that the application does not start in dev mode now.

Before:
[image: link]

Now:

[image: link]

How to run the application in dev mode?

Comment: please add code samples and error text to the question. What is it not important to have, then leave as links to images.

Comment: Ok, thx. I add images and code examples. Ask if you need more

Comment: Was your previous version < 2.3.7? If so, this answer should help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272840/minify-client-through-play-framework

Comment: I would recommend to look at Migration guide for this version: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24. Or even migrate to the latest Play version and start debugging from it.